# What is the problem of increasing the time encryption of my stream cipher algorithm?

Tags: c#, security, cryptography, aes

I have my own stream cipher algorithm, and I made a comparison between it and AES performance. I tested it on several files with different sizes(to 500KB). Its encryption/decryption time is less than AES for files about 500KB. but with files more than 500KB, its encryption time  is more than AES but still its decryption time is the least one.

```
public static byte[] AES_Encrypt(byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
{
    byte[] encryptedBytes = null;

    byte[] saltBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged())
    {
            AES.KeySize = 128;
            AES.BlockSize = 128;
            var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, 
            saltBytes, 1000);
            AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
            AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);
            AES.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
            AES.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;

            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, 
            AES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(bytesToBeEncrypted, 0, 
                bytesToBeEncrypted.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            encryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
        }
        ms.Close();
    }

    return encryptedBytes;
}

public static byte[] AES_Decrypt(byte[] bytesToBeDecrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
{
    byte[] decryptedBytes = null;
    byte[] saltBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            AES.KeySize = 128;
            AES.BlockSize = 128;
            var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, 
      saltBytes, 1000);
            AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
            AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);
            AES.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
            AES.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;                      

            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, 
           AES.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(bytesToBeDecrypted, 0, 
               bytesToBeDecrypted.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            decryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    return decryptedBytes;
}
```

Comment: From what I see, your 'encryption' doubles the size of the source data. so 'encrypting' 500kb source data with your code will result in 1000kb encrypted data...

Comment: If this is just for toying around with some concepts, so be it. But make no mistake, creating a *soundly* constructed encryption algorithm is not something to try to do lightly.